# Which is the difference between two methods to calculate the battery level in android?

Tags: android, batterylevel

in my application i display the battery level.. i get the battery level in this way:

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```

And it's ok i can see the percentage.. but online i found another way:

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

What's the difference? Why i would divide the level with the scale? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you get different numbers :)

the scale is the  `integer containing the maximum battery level.` So with the second method you get the percentage (hence it is called `batteryPct`) you have left. With the first you get the asolute number of your battery level. It is defined as `integer field containing the current battery level, from 0 to EXTRA_SCALE.`

Comment: Scale is hardcoded to 100 in the android source code, so it's basically the same, unless some manufacturer chooses to change scale to something else. (http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java#BATTERY_SCALE)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_SCALE), the SCALE is the max value:

> public static final String EXTRA_SCALE
>
> Added in API level 5 Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer
>   containing the maximum battery level.
>
> Constant Value: "scale"

And the [LEVEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_LEVEL) is the current level:

> public static final String EXTRA_LEVEL
>
> Added in API level 5 Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer field
>   containing the current battery level, from 0 to EXTRA_SCALE.
>
> Constant Value: "level"

So basically, the first gives you an absolute number and the second gives you a percentage.